# The meaning of arrow pointing to buffer in the OpenCL class diagram

Tags: uml, opencl

I am studying in the approximate structure of OpenCL.

[OpenCL UML Class Diagram](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/classDiagram.html)

1. I am wondering why there an arrow points from the butter below MemObject to  itself.

   Is the reason that we can copy one buffer object to another buffer object using function clEnqueueCopyBuffer().

   or we can pass date between "host memory " & "compute device memory" ?

   or Something else ??
2. MemObject mentioned in the OpenCL UML Class Diagram  means compute device or host memory or the both?

Comment: At least some of the multiplicities in that diagram are on the wrong ends. E.g., a buffer must always compose exactly one buffer? Whahuh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. - The reason why a "MemObject" is pointed by "Buffer" and "Image" is because "MemObject" is abstracting both (inherits from). Most functions will not care when doing a copy or setting an argument to a kernel if it is a "Buffer" or "Image", only if it is a "MemObject".
   - A buffer can point to itself, because a buffer object can be a sub-buffer of another one. In fact you can create infinite amount of buffers that are sub-buffers of another one.
2. - The class diagram refers to abstract objects used by the API. Wether these objects reside on host or device is not relevant in that diagram. Only the relation between objects.
   - Example: A Queue has ONLY one context, but a context has * (0...N) queues.

Comment: It's not **has** "Buffer" but **inherts from**.